# Small Tab Bar Height with Sliding Bar Under Like FlipBoard in SWIFT or OBJECTIVE-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-experience, tabbar

How can we imitate the tab bar in the Flipboard App? It has a smaller height compared to the default tab bar height given when you embed a view to a tab bar controller. I know there is a function for tab bar height but then, the thing that confuses me about the Flipboard app's tab bar is the RED thin bar under the tab bar icons that slides out across the tab bar and stops under a pressed icon.
[image]

I have managed to imitate it by using 1 ViewController, with a ScrollView to change scenes(View controllers are being added as subviews inside ScrollView) and UIView as TAB BAR. Thus, animation can easily happen.

This is how I managed to imitate it. 
[image]

But, I wonder, if there is a better way to attain this Flipboard-like style of tab bar?

If you have a Flipboard app. You can see it for yourself.